# How to open a PHP file with .gif extension?

Tags: php, apache, browser

I need to open a PHP file with .gif extension like a PHP file in browser. How can I do that? I running PHP 5.6 and apache.

Thanks

Comment: You can change the mime type of image/gif to application/x-httpd-php   with php Or htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in .htaccess

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .gif
```

Comment: Thanks, It works but Is there an option to add this in the file?